# Create a WebRTC VideoTrack with a "custom" Capturer on Android with libjingle

Tags: android, webrtc, libjingle

How to use a "custom" video capturer to create a VideoTrack and provide frames?

The classic approach to create a VideoTrack is:

**1 - Get a VideoCapturer instance**

```
VideoCapturer capturer = VideoCapturer.create(name);
```

**2 - Create a VideoSource**

```
VideoSource videoSource = peerconnectionFactory.createVideoSource(capturer, videoConstraints);
```

**3 - Create a VideoTrack using the video source**

```
VideoTrack videoTrack = peerconnectionFactory.createVideoTrack("Label", videoSource);
```

**4 - Add the track to the MediaStream**

---

I was wondering if there is a way to change **step one**. Instead of using the native Capturer instance, use an Android one, and provide the frames to the VideoTrack using the callback:

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
   // provide the frames to the VideoTrack
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't know what you want to achieve.Actually it is not native capturer. It is using android camera class to capture and frame is passes to native lib.May be the code you are using is inside the jar.

Comment: There is a class VideoCaptureAndroid.java in jar file from where the frames are capture and passes to native liberary.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia, yes I saw it, but as soon as I remember it all the "important" method were private so it looked like it had to be implemented

Comment: yes you are right.But if if you are using source coded not jar you can change it whatever you want.

Comment: What you want to achieve by intercepting frames?

Comment: Mainly I want to be able to modify, edit or adding manually frames to the video track, and eventually provides frame for an external video source (e.g webcam)

Comment: @Manza Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: @Manza Have you managed to do that?

Comment: @Manza Hi have you done this successfully? (after 6 years :) )

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way (although a bit "hacky") to do this is to copy the source of `RTCVideoCapturer` to a local class withing your project and just use that local class. You can now edit the class to suit your needs. Even when not copying the file but actually building your own, it's probably better to copy large parts of the existing capturer than to reinvent the wheel.