# Create a WebRTC VideoTrack with a “custom” Capturer using C++

Tags: c++, video-streaming, webrtc

Is there a way (or hack) to let me use a "custom" video capturer to create a VideoTrack and provide frames to it ?

The classic way to build a VideoTrack is :

Get a VideoCapturer Instance :

```
std::unique_ptr<cricket::VideoCapturer> capturer;
```

Create a VideoSource with a provided capturer :

```
 rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::VideoTrackSourceInterface> videoSource = peer_connection_factory_->CreateVideoSource(std::move(capturer), NULL);
```

Create a VideoTrack using the VideoSource :

```
rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::VideoTrackInterface> video_track;

video_track = peer_connection_factory_->CreateVideoTrack(kVideoLabel, videoSource);
```

I was wondering if there is a way to override step one, instead of using the native one, using a custom capturer, so that i can provide the frames to the video track using a callback. That will let me use any video source (file, yuv stream...) and be very flexible.

Any advice on this one ?

This question is a C++ reference to : [Create a WebRTC VideoTrack with a “custom” Capturer on Android with libjingle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23654425/create-a-webrtc-videotrack-with-a-custom-capturer-on-android-with-libjingle)

Comment: Another Java reference: *[Converting Motion JPEG to WebRTC](https://www.frozenmountain.com/developers/blog/archive/converting-motion-jpeg-to-webrtc/)*

Comment: It's perfectly OK to have related questions. It's nice to have them listed explicitly.

Comment: ahh okay my bad, i did not understood, I'll edit right away.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a way to make my own native C++ Video Capture. Basically you have to override some functions from webrtc::I420BufferInterface and cricket::VideoCapturer. 
If someone wants any further explanations please feel free to ask.

Comment: Can you please explain further on what to do to make it work? I'm not restricted to implementing a C++ capturer, a Java one would also work.

Comment: Hi Hakeem, can you please share an example? I am trying to use a RTSP stream to create a VideoCapture source. There is a library called JavaCV which can give me RTSP stream to fragments. Now I need to find a way to integrate the frames/fragments into WebRTC

Comment: Hi Hakeem, I'm also trying to achieve the same in C++. Could you please direct me to some documentation or a sample?

Comment: Hi could you please provide some more details? Thanks!