# Custom VideoSource for JS WebRTC running in the WebView of Android/iOS devices?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, webview, webrtc

We want to use a custom video source instead of normal sources like cameras for WebRTC. There [do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49493923/how-to-custom-webrtc-video-source) [exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61160558/custom-video-source-for-webrtc-on-android) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23654425/create-a-webrtc-videotrack-with-a-custom-capturer-on-android-with-libjingle) if using WebRTC library on *native* Android/iOS code. However, our environment is different:

We have a native Android/iOS app. The app has a WebView (or, if you want, have a JavaScriptCore engine or anything else), and many JavaScript code is running inside it. The js code (*not* the native code) is using WebRTC, and we want *this* to have a custom video source.

Thanks very much for and ideas!